How do you remember the algorithm for rotating a square matrix?
The algorithm for rotating a square matrix 90 degrees is neat, and it is documented here and here. However, it is difficult to remember, and requires one to look it up first in order to implement it.
Is there an easy way to remember this algorithm? Or is it common to just look it up in order to implement it?
(In my opinion, even the most accomplished computer scientist would have to look up this algorithm ten years after seeing it for the first time... it is difficult to derive.)

What is difficult to remember here? Do you mean you will have to remember the sequence $(i,j) \rightarrow (j, n-1-i) \rightarrow (n-1-i, n-1-j), \rightarrow (n-1-j, i) \rightarrow (i,j)$ or the idea of cycles itself? The sequence can be derived on the spot in $20$ seconds max. The idea can be difficult if you don't have experience with that kind of thinking, but thats where practice comes in.

As @EnEm says, it’s not an algorithm that you ever try to memorise. It’s trivial. Draw a square on a piece of paper, rotate by 90 degrees, and it’s trivial.

Here is a two-step process, that is somewhat easy to understand (and implement).
Step 1: transpose the square matrix
 1  2  3                 1  4  7
 4  5  6   will become   2  5  8
 7  8  9                 3  6  9

Step 2: Take a horizontal reflection of the matrix
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9
--------- mirror
 3  6  9
 2  5  8
 1  4  7

